# JMeter remove a single character from string variable

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I am trying to remove "/" character from my specific string but I cannot succeed.

My example string:

```
F@S@3440642@SOW/AGT@10928415@F@-1@undefined@false
```

I need to remove that "/" character between "SOW" and "AGT" substrings. I tried some tricks with JSR223 but I couldn't do it; either get an error in my logs, or I cannot remove that character from the string.

Could you please help me with how to remove "/" character by using JSR223?

Comment: What tricks did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [String.replaceAll() function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) like:

```
vars.put('somevar', vars.get('somevar').replaceAll('/', ''))
```

Demo:

[image]

in the above snippet `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see JavaDoc for details and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements.

---

Also be aware that there are [__strReplace()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) and [__strReplaceRegex()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplaceRegexsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) custom JMeter Functions so you don't need to do any Groovy scripting at all

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java's String replace:

```
String token = "F@S@3440642@SOW/AGT@10928415@F@-1@undefined@false";
log.info(token.replace("/",""));
```